# Use both type and integer as template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, singleton, c++14

For the code I am working on, I have a class that uses a "context" singleton. In order to be a bit more coder-friendly, I passes the Singleton class used as a template to the object. For example, something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

class DefaultCtx {
private:
    DefaultCtx() {};
    const char *str = "default";
public:
    static const char* get()
    {
        static DefaultCtx instance;
        return instance.str;
    }
    DefaultCtx(DefaultCtx const &) = delete;
    void operator=(DefaultCtx const &) = delete;
};  

// Context for 64bits.    
class Ctx64 {
private:
    Ctx64() {};
    const char *str = "64";
public:
    static const char* get()
    {
        static Ctx64 instance;
        return instance.str;
    }
    Ctx64(Ctx64 const &) = delete;
    void operator=(Ctx64 const &) = delete;
};  

template<typename Ctx>
class UsesCtx {
public:
    UsesCtx() { std::cout << "Constructed using singleton " << Ctx::get() << std::endl; }
};
```

This scheme works fine, and I'm quite happy with the need to pass context as template parameter when constructing my objects. However, since `Ctx64` is used for 64 bits representation, I wanted to add a little syntaxic sugar and use `UsesCtx<64>` :

```
int main() {
    UsesCtx<DefaultCtx> a;
    UsesCtx<Ctx64> b;

    // UsesCtx<64> c; //< I don't know how to achieve that.

}
```

As I noted here, I don't know how to achieve it. I tried to redefine the class with an integer template, but that gives me the following error (compiled with `g++ example.cpp --std=c++14`)

```
// Gives compile error "error: template parameter ‘class Ctx’ redeclared here as ‘int n’"
template<int n>
class UsesCtx {
public:
    UsesCtx() { std::cout << "Constructed using singleton " << n << std::endl; }
};
```

**Is there any way I can have my class `UsesCtx` with both a class template parameter and an int template parameter?** Of course, I can always instantiate with `UsesCtx<Ctx64>`, so this is not vital. But it didn't expected it to be hard to do.

Comment: Sorry, you are missing vital information. An int is not going to be valid for `64::get()` neither do you specify the additional functons that `Ctx` must provide.

Comment: Ok, but is there any way to specify that constructing `UsesCtx<64>` means constructing `UsesCtx<Ctx64>` ?

Comment: best bet prolly would be `template<int N> using Ctx = ...;` which will make it `UsesCtx<Ctx<64>>`. Or making `Ctx64` a template<int N>` directly and employ explicit instantiation for 32 and 64 possibly.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb : I tried your approach of using `template<int n>` onto the context instead of `UsesCtx`. It works fine, and seems more logical now that I wrote it. Thanks! :)